# Unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I am using Kotlin with Android Studio And when I try to run my code I have this error : Unresolved reference. Here is my code :

```
private fun loadLocation(){

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "localhost",
            Response.Listener<String> { s ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(s)
                    val array = obj.getJSONArray("response")

                    for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                        val objectArtist = array.getJSONObject(i)
                        val value = objectArtist.getString("value")

                        val value100 = value.toDouble()

                    }
    //This line below displays the right value

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value100.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })

    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requestQueue.add<String>(stringRequest)

    //This line below displays the wrong value

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value100.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



}
```

The problem is this : If I am looking at this line :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value100.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

This first line displays the good values the first time but if I try this line at the end of the code it does not work... I try to declare the variable after `private fun loadLocation(){` but when I try to displays this I got 0. And I need absolutely to get the value of my variable. Thank you for your help !

EDIT :

I tried also this code :

```
private fun loadLocation(){

                        var value100 = 0


    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "localhost",
            Response.Listener<String> { s ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(s)
                    val array = obj.getJSONArray("response")

                    for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                        val objectArtist = array.getJSONObject(i)
                        val value = objectArtist.getString("value")

                        value100 = value.toDouble()

                    }
    //This line below displays the right value

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value100.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })

    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requestQueue.add<String>(stringRequest)

    //This line below displays the wrong value

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value100.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



}
```

And in this case I get for the first Toast the correct value and for the second I get 0 which is not the correct value...

Comment: It seems like you do not understand async calls/mulithreading. Adding something to request queue doesn't means that listener was called. [Example](http://ideone.com/PPHi95)

Comment: A variable can only be used inside the scope where it's declared. If you tried declaring it in the enclosing scope and still had problems, maybe you accidentally *re-declared* it instead of using the existing one?

Comment: Actually I try to declare outside the scope the variable equals to 0 but what I don't achieve is to get the new value of the variable... How can I do this ?

Comment: So how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the variable inside a `for` loop, hence it will only be visible inside that loop. To make it visible to all the code inside the function, declare it at the function scope. To be able to change the value later, use `var` instead of `val`. `val` is similar to Java's `final`: the value can only be assigned once.

Comment: I edited my post but unfortunately it did not solve my problem :/

Comment: What is your code trying to achieve? The second invocation of `Toast` will always have `0` as the value of `value100`, so you might as well hardcode it.

Comment: But what I don't understant is this : at the beginning  value100 = 0 but then normally  value100 = value.toDouble() so according to me the second Toast should display value.toDouble()

Comment: That will happen in the callback, which is going to be invoked when the Volley request finishes. This will almost always happen after the second `Toast` call, which will just do `0.toString()`.

Comment: Okay I am beginning to understand.. So to solve this I have to insert a kind of wait ? Or How can I achieve to get the new value of value100 ? Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: You're welcome! Again, what are you trying to achieve? If you want to display the `Toast` when the response is returned - the callback is a perfect place for that. Your first `Toast` already does that.

Comment: Actually it is very long to explain...but what I want is to get the value to use it in an other function so for me it is difficult to put all in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

The "right value" call to `makeText` is made inside your listener, which is called asynchronously -- *after* the response to the GET request is received. That is why it always displays the right value.

The "wrong value" call to `makeText` is made synchronously (which is generally going to be *before* the response to the GET request is received). That is why it would (almost) always display the wrong value (even if `value100` were in scope).

Comment: Thank you I understood that, but I suppose there is a way to solve this right ? Because I have to get this value to use it in a function. Maybe I can put a kind of wait ?

Comment: One way to approach that is to use a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures-and-callables) may be helpful.

Comment: I think you're right Future will help me, Is it easy to modify my code to solve the problem ? How I have to put Future in my code ? Many thanks !

Comment: "Easiness" varies by the person :-). It will probably take some time and effort to familiarize yourself with the concepts.Read that tutorial, or look for others that may be easier for you to follow.

Comment: Thank you but for me, I assume it is the first time I hear about Future so thank you ! I mean what is the most simple example to understand Future ?

Comment: If you are targeting Java 8, look at this [CompletableFuture tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture). Otherwise, [this one on Future](http://www.baeldung.com/java-future).

Comment: I saw this code on stackoverflow which seems to work : `RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(), future, future);
requestQueue.add(request);

try {
  JSONObject response = future.get(); // this will block
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // exception handling
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // exception handling
}` but I don't know how to modify my code :/